# Generating menus in client side via abp.nav.menus.MainMenu

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate

I am working with ASPNet Boilerplate. In the documentation I was going through the [NavigationProvider](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Navigation). What I wanted to do was to define how the menus should appear without having to hard code them at client-end.

However as the documentation points out, I couldn't find how it's being used in the downloaded template (Asp.net core with AngularJS - version 3.6.0) since there are no references made to NavigationProvider in any of the classes.

The sample Task application seems to be for an older version of Abp.

I would highly appreciate if anyone can point me to a documentation/sample for this.

Comment: ASP.NET Core template comes with Angular, not AngularJS.

Comment: sorry that was a typo! But still the question is valid i guess...

Comment: if you are using ASP.NET Core & Angular version, menu items are defined on the client side. So, you can order them as you want, see https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/blob/master/angular/src/app/layout/sidebar-nav.component.ts.